# How to initialize one parent at a time in multiple inheritance?

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following class inheriting from classes `A` and `B`:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 2
class B:
    def __init__(self,u):
        self.y = u + 2
class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        #self.y should be 4 here
```

How do I initialize B only after initializing A? Using `super(C,self).__init__()` doesn't let me use attributes of A into B.

Comment: Where does `u` get specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't HAVE to use super.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 2
class B:
    def __init__(self,u):
        self.y = u + 2
class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        B.__init__(self, self.x)
```

Now, that does mean some pretty tight coupling, in that `C` has to be way too aware of what `A.__init__` does.

Comment: Works exactly as I wanted, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("A was initialized")
        self.x = 2
    def getX(self):
        return self.x
class B:
    def __init__(self, u):
        print("B was initialized")
        self.u  = u +2
        
class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        A.__init__(self)
        B.__init__(self, self.getX())
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, with `super`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 2
class B:
    def __init__(self,u):
        self.y = u + 2
class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        super(A, self).__init__(self.x)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to pass attributes in between classes use something like a return statement. Then in your B class use whatever the A class returned.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).